# What's the simplest way to get Eclipse running in a web browser?

Tags: eclipse, architecture, node.js, eclipse-plugin

I was looking at the [eclim](http://eclim.org/) project and realized that if a headless Eclipse instance can be integrated within vim why not with a client running over a browser. I'd like to do a proof of concept that simply lets me see the project explorer and the contents of any file I select. I don't have a lot of experience with SWT or the Eclipse Runtime but here's what I'm envisioning as a first step:

```
   eclipse headless runtime 
       <-- local --> 
some plugin that talks to node 
       <-- cloud --> 
      node.js server
```

Does something like this (a) sound feasible and (b) what are the specific components I should look into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Eclipse [RAP](http://eclipse.org/rap/) (Rich Ajax Platform) project. It can get you there.

Comment: Looks very promising, makes me wonder if someone's already setup an Eclipse instance using RAP. Thanks.